# Why does it make sense to define the Probability mass function of e.g. the binomial distribution like this?

Tags: notation, probability-distributions

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) (for example) the Probability mass function of for example a the binomial distribution is given by

$$
f(k,n,p):=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

In some literature I read

$$
P_{n,p}:=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \delta_k
$$

where $\delta_k$ is the Dirac delta function.

I see that the result is the same, because $\delta_k$ nullifies each not needed addend. Why this verbosity? Does it have a sense, that I didn't get so far?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Could you be more specific about where you saw this notation?  Also, in your second equation, the right hand side is a constant independent of $k$ since $k$ is a dummy variable. Can you double check that equation?

Comment: @Srivatsan: There was a typo, sorry. It is script of a german professor. I'll give the link anyway. [You can find the notation in this pdf](http://www-wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/~ferrari/Lectures/WS11ProbaI/wt.pdf) on page 44.

Comment: After the recent edits: Now I see the intended meaning. $\delta_k$ is not a variable as I assumed, but a function that is $1$ at $k$ and $0$ everywhere else. This is mostly for notational convenience; also manipulating algebraic expressions becomes easier using the second notation as compared to the first.

Comment: Rather than a function, each $\delta_k$ is a (probability) measure (as $P_{n,p}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page considers a *discrete* probability distribution defined on the natural numbers. The use of the Dirac measure $\delta_k$ suggests that a probability density function of a *continuous* random variable is defined. In the latter setting the former definition would not do, because $\tbinom nk$ can be given a non-zero meaning at non-integral $k$ using the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) (or using the Gamma function if you prefer), and this would not be the right thing for getting a probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As Didier Piau hinted, the first expression is a density function for your random variable (implicitely distributed on the integers), while the second expression is the law of your random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here $\delta_k$ is a set-function defined such that for any $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$,
$$\delta_k(A) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  {1} \quad{\text{if}}\quad k \in A \\
  {0} \quad{\text{if}}\quad k \notin A \\ 
\end{gathered} \right.$$
i.e., expressed as an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), $\delta_k(A) = [k \in A]$.

Thus, the *probability measure* $P_{n,p}$ is such that for any event $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$,
$$
P_{n,p}(A) = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \delta_k(A) = \sum_{k \in \{0,1,\cdots,n\}\cap A} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$